# Redirecting a specific file to the 404 page with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

I have a file that lives on the web server (long story), in this example called "secretFile.sh". If a user *happens* to know this file exists at `mysite.com/secretFile.sh` I need to redirect that file url to my 404 page using htaccess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /secretFile\.sh[?/\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]
```